# Creating extra gravity by spinning an object close to the speed of light?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity

To give a concrete example, [PSR_J1748-2446ad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSR_J1748-2446ad) has an equatorial surface velocity around 0.24c.
Does it exert additional gravity due to its spin?

The concept of 'relativistic mass' is sometimes used for some things, but from what I've read it's not a very good approximation for gravity, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: For these types of objects you can't think of gravity like this, or relativistic mass. One must use general relativity. So, for example, you could treat this spinning object by a Kerr metric, so spacetime curvature <=> gravity.